# Override CSS remove property

Tags: html, css, properties, overriding

I'm using a lib and i want to remove a property on a class. What is proper way to do it ?

Example :
Lib.css

```
div {
    width: 100%;
}
```

and custom.css

```
div {
    width: none; //something like that
}
```

Comment: `width: auto;` should be what you're after

Comment: `width: unset;` removes the property

Comment: width: auto!important; - If @NickParsons don't work

Answer (score 3):

Every rule in CSS has a different default value. Many might have `none` or `auto` as default. Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference) for Reference. Search for 'Initial value'

#### Example

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width
Initial value: auto

#### Edit

You can also use the special value [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial), if you don't need to support MSIE browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to read about CSS specificity here in the docs: 
[CSS Specificity: Mozilla Developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and check my answer down below.

There are several ways to overwrite CSS properties from external libraries.

**Case 1:** if you're using Bootstrap or Zurb Foundation via npm package, 
you need to change a variable value that is responsible for given property and place it after importing all library files to ovewrite correctyly eg.

```
import 'files from library.sass';

// my settings
$default-width: 80%;
```

**Case 2:** if you're using CDN to deliver your library you can use a more specific CSS selector to overwrite given property eg:

to overwrite div selector

```
div {}   ----> div.my-class {}
```

The second technique, but for sure **not recommended** is to use `!important` declaration. But remember, using !important declaration often causes many problems during the development process. It is always better to find a more specific selector than use !important.